# How to allow other people to use desktop application that relies on database?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, desktop-application

So I've created a java desktop application using Swing.  It stores data entered into the application in a MySQL database (localhost).  Now how would someone else be able to use the application ?  Would they require a MySQL database as well ?  What are the best practices for doing this.  I do eventually hope to submit the entire project folder to github.

Comment: The question depends, if you want to continue running the application using the local database, then you could simply create an installer which installed you application (and MySQL) or even consider using a stand alone database like H2 instead.  If you wanted people to have the ability to share the data, then you would need to consider using a centralised database server, but this then raises issues of security and access

Comment: The first option seems like the simpler option.  So doing some research I found a tool for packaging java applications on the Java Platform called izPack.  Its multi-platform which is ideal.  But is this really good practice ?  I mean I'm forcing the user to install mysql in addition the the application.

Comment: If you're only using MySQL in standalone mode, then no, I wouldn't consider it a good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I would have to ask first whether this program is a demo or classroom project or if it's a real application, because the answer would be different.

For a demo project, it would be fine to post your code to github, and also dump the database to a .sql file and commit that as well.  MySQL ships with a handy tool called *mysqldump* that will do just that - export the entire contents of your database.  Then a person can clone your github repo, install MySQL locally, and run your sql script to get a copy of your database.  Once they follow those steps, they should be able to run a copy of your swing app on their machine just like you can.  One caveat here though is it's best practice to avoid putting very large files (especially binary files) in git.  I'm not sure what you need, but if you can put a small sql file out there that's definitely preferred.

That's a segue into the other answer which is hosting *your* MySQL database somewhere.  For a real application, making copies just won't do.  Then what you need to do is host your database centrally using a service like [this one](http://www.freemysqlhosting.net/) and allow your users to connect to it.  You can still use mysqldump to get your database out there on the web after creating it on localhost.  If you go this route though, you'll definitely want to avoid putting your database connection strings on github.  Again, this scenario is really only useful if your app is intended to be used for real - don't bother with hosting if you don't need it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well the project is somewhat a real project/resume builder project.  Interesting, I didn't know you could host the database centrally for free, although I don't think that would be necessary since the data should be stored locally rather than publicly for each user.  Also  when you run my project everything is self-contained.  Namely, it only requires username, password, port, etc from the user, and the application creates the db and all associated tables (if not already created) and then launches the application gui.  So it doesn't actually contain any sql files.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should install mysql with a public ip, then alter the connection to mysql with the ip,the example follows below

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/db";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

if you want to run java program like exe file, package the java program to a jar file with jre